# behavior of HTML <a> tag when href=""

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have this HTML code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/Lp7e7/))

There I have used an `< a >` tag with `href=""`

I cannot get the expected functionality(simply show and hide a div). But when I changed it to `href="#"` it works fine.

Why is it acting like that when I use `href=""`?

Can anybody please explain this behavior ?

Comment: Come on guys ! why anwser this ? why not just give a link ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222466/how-to-stop-href-going-anywhere

Comment: @l2aelba The link you provided is dead.  That's why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click event is also ending up triggering the href. In the case of the empty link, this is causing a page refresh, whereas in the case of the # it simply goes to a page anchor. In your click method, use preventDefault() to stop the link from getting followed. See documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

To specifically answer with relation to your code, you would change to this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inboxHeaderLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#newMessage').show();
        $('#viewMessage').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With empty `href` in `<a  href="">`  will Reload the page.

You can use `href="javascript:void(0);"`

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fWd9F/1)

or

you can use [event.preventdefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on click of the anchor tag .

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fWd9F/)

Answer (score 2):

As Stated in RFC 2396: A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the current document. In other words, an empty URI reference within a document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document.

So, to avoid this you either have to set `href="#"` **OR** `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `href=""` reloads the page

The `href="#"` part is a commonly used way to make sure the link doesn't lead anywhere on it's own.

The #-attribute is used to create a link to some other section in the same document. So if you specify # without any name like in your case, the link leads nowhere.

You can also use `href="javascript:;"`

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 option.if you want to prevent a tag default event through html then write like this

```
<div id="inboxHeader">                  
    <div id="inboxNewMessage"><a id="inboxHeaderLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Click</a></div>
</div>
```

And if you want to stop it through jquery then write it like this

```
$('#inboxHeaderLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#newMessage').show();
    $('#viewMessage').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `preventDefault()`:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp7e7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`href=""` is a hyperlink to the current page. In other words: it will refresh the page.
`href="#"` is a "hyperlink" that gets you to the top of your page, but **without refreshing** which is what you need. If you refresh, the green square will be reloaded and reset after the JS code fires.

Answer (score 1):

empty `href=""` will navigate to the page , so stop the default event using

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Lp7e7/3/